# Windows 7 Green Load Bar Stuck and never finish loading,

Tags: windows

Here is my issues, which i am currently having, in my windows 7, When i go to one specific folder, .Please take a look,

[image]

This is not my file, but just to get an idea, there is 10 file max no more than 500 MB, i am not able to remove it, or cut it, or move it, it starts that green bar loading and never finish, The problem is, after getting into this folder, my SONY VAIO starts, overheating and if i did not restart, nothing can stop it to be cool down . I have reinstalled windows 2 weeks ago, i don't think this should be issue regarding it.

Please, help me what the hell i should do with this GREEN BAR< to stop this headache,

Comment: maybe the dvd is corrupt?

Comment: It's not my window, and it is not on DVD< the folder is on DESKTOP, so on C Disk, i have disabled thumbnail view and it looks its loading faster, but still stucking